# Can I invoke any C# method from Universal JS App(.NET)?

Tags: javascript, c#, win-universal-app

I created universal js app in VS2015. I want to know: is it possible to call C# method or create instance of object out Universal js app?
I have been tried to find a solution for 3 hours but I haven't found it yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your C# code in a Windows Runtime Component (WRC) and then consume that WRC from your JavaScript app. The JavaScript app can create objects from the WRC and call the object properties and methods the same way it would call natively JavaScript objects.

See MSDN's [Walkthrough: Creating a simple component in C# or Visual Basic and calling it from JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779077.aspx) for an example.